# QTableWidget connecting row selection in multiple tables

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to connect a row selection in multiple `QTableWidgets` which have the same number of rows.

What I'm trying to achieve: selecting a row in one table by clicking on a vertical header button -> other tables has their rows selected at the same index.

At this moment It doesn't work right. If I select a row in a first table, it instantly removes a selection from it and selects a cell in the same row of the latest table added to layout.

There are methods I'm using to connect row selection in a first table to a function:

```py
    def __synchronize_table_row_selection(self):
        self.supplyInfoTable.verticalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(lambda index: self.__select_table_rows(index))

    def __select_table_rows(self, index):
        tables = [self.layout().itemAt(i).widget() for i in range(self.layout().count())][1:]
        for table in tables:
            table.selectRow(index)
```

I've seen people somehow used `QTableWidget.verticalHeader().sectionClicked` in c++ code, but I think I've messed up something and there's a mistake in this part of code.

**UPD**

Here's a minimal example:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        self.supplyInfoTable = QTableWidget(40, 2)

        self.scoreInfoTable = QTableWidget(40, 2)
        self.scoreInfoTable.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.AllEditTriggers)

        self.dataInfoTable = QTableWidget(40, 2)
        # if set to NoEditTriggers, then selection doesn't disappear
        self.dataInfoTable.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.AllEditTriggers)

        self.dataInfoTable.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.scoreInfoTable.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)

        self.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())

        self.layout().addWidget(self.supplyInfoTable)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.scoreInfoTable)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.dataInfoTable)

        self.__synchronize_table_row_selection()

    def __select_table_rows(self, index):
        tables = [self.layout().itemAt(i).widget() for i in range(self.layout().count())][1:]
        for table in tables:
            table.selectRow(index)

    def __synchronize_table_row_selection(self):
        self.supplyInfoTable.verticalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(self.__select_table_rows)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If the last table has `setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)`, it works, but it highlights cells in first table with blue, cells in other tables with gray. I suppose it should highlight all of them, doesn't it?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Why don't you add just `print(table, index)` statement just below `table.selectRow(index)` to find out for which tables and indexes this was called? Printing stuff which you are not sure about is the most useful way of debugging.

Comment: Btw. it seems to me that all you need is to synchronize selections. So why don;t you share the same selection model? That is the correct way to sync selections. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#sharing-selections-among-views

Comment: @V.K. sharing the same selection model among two views only works as long as they also share the same data model, which is not possible for QTableWidget (using `setModel` is not allowed).

Comment: @Artem two things: 1. `sectionClicked` already provides the index, so using a lambda is pointless; 2. using `layout().itemAt(i).widget()` is not safe because the it's not guaranteed that the layout item has a widget and that it's a table (both cases could lead to a crash).

Comment: @V.K. Yep, agreed, but I've already done it, and it shows what I expected to see: 2nd and 3d table with the same index as the 1st one. Its obvious now that problem doesn't lie in wrong table/index selection. For the unknown reason, the row highlight (blue one on windows) works only for the 1st table

Comment: @Artem the selection color is blue for views that have keyboard *focus*, unfocused widgets show selected items in gray (colors might change based on the OS and current style).

Comment: @musicamante, got it, thanks! Then, is there any way to remove this (blue) highlight at all?

Comment: @Artem you can use stylesheets to set proper colors of selected items (note that a hint for the selection should always be clear to the user); see [customizing QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview).